# I submitted manuscript to a special issue of a Springer journal. The review date has passed. What should I do now?

Tags: journals, peer-review, special-issue

The date of the 1st round review was 1st November, but they have extended the date to 1 December. Now, it is almost 19 days overdue. What should I do? Should I send an email to editor or guest editor for that special issue?

Is it too early or not? If you suggest to send an email, please help me with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not worry about this at this stage.  In publishing (and organizing conferences, etc.), almost everything takes longer than the original deadlines would suggest.  At this stage, the reviews may have been completed; but then the editors have to go through all the reviews themselves and decide what to do with each paper.  Moreover, there are probably a few referees who are late turning in their reports, and the whole process can be pushed back several weeks.  Add to this the fact that early December tends to be a very busy time for many academics (semester winding down, final grading to be done), three or four weeks from the reviewing deadline seems a totally unremarkable delay in hearing back from the editorial staff.

I would recommend not doing anything, until at least some time next year.  However, if you wish, you could send an e-mail to the editor, asking about the status of your submission.  Keep in mind though that replying to requests like that just take up more of an editor's time, and it will probably have very little marginal effect on how quickly your paper is dealt with.

Comment: would sending an email is ethical?

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi:  Yes, there would be no ethical problem with doing that.  I don't think it will help you that much, but it might provide a bit of information about the status of your submission.

Comment: @BuzzThank you sir....you are right actually....Since 22 days the status is showing is : Reviews completed....

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi Is that the status for your paper, or the status for *all* papers submitted to the special issue? It's a peculiar feature of special issues that the (non)acceptance of your paper may depend not only on your own reviews, but also on the reviews of other submissions (since there are page limits for the entire special issue). In the end, a couple of late reviews for some submission may delay the acceptance decision for a many other submissions.

Comment: @Uwe It is the status of my paper....I don't know about others...whats your suggestion....should i send email...or wait for another 10 days...

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi As I said, the acceptance of your paper may depend on the reviews of *other* papers, and some of them may still be missing. Be patient. These delays are completely normal.